# How to check if Javascript object value is array and not empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Before I run some code, I need to check whether the data I'm passing (from a JSON file) is correct.

Specifically, I'm trying to check if the email exists and my **body** object:
- has at least one key
- each key has a value
- and the value must be an array with at least one item populating it.

```
const email = "john@gmail.com"
const body = {
   "fruit": ["apple"],
   "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"]
}
```

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

```
if (email && Object.keys(body).length > 0 && Object.keys(body) instanceof Array) {
   // run some code
} else {
  // log error
}
```

Is **instanceof** the best method here? I'm wondering if I should use .isArray() instead. Also should I be performing this on Object.keys or Object.value?

Thanks :)

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(body).every(key => Array.isArray(body[key])));` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `Object.keys` and check that each value is an array and has at least one value.

```
Object.keys(body).every(key => Array.isArray(body[key]) && body[key].length !== 0)
```

This will check, for each body key, that it's value is an array (using `Array.isArray`) and that it has at least one element in it (using `body[key].length`).

Furtherly, `.every` returns true only if **all the tests passed**.

[Array.every MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

[Object.keys MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const email = "john@gmail.com"
const body = {
   "fruit": ["apple"],
   "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"]
}

if (email && Object.keys(body).length > 0 && Object.keys(body).every(key => Array.isArray(body[key]) && body[key].length !== 0)) {
   console.log('hooray!');
} else {
  // log error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to check the `Object.values` of the `body`, and see if `.every` one of them is an array with nonzero length:

```js
const email = "john@gmail.com"
const body = {
   "fruit": ["apple"],
   "vegetables": ["carrot", "beans"]
}
const ok = email && Object.values(body).every(val => Array.isArray(val) && val.length !== 0);
if (ok) {
  console.log('ok');
} else {
  // handle error
}
```

The problem with

> `Object.keys(body) instanceof Array`

is that this will *always* return `true` if `body` is an object:

```js
const email = "john@gmail.com"
const body = { foo: 'bar' }
console.log(Object.keys(body) instanceof Array);
```